# Angular 2 Not Deserializing .NET List<T>

Tags: json, angular, typescript, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I'm having problems deserializing a .NET List into an Angular 2 array. I keep receiving an error:

**ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object...NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.**

I've checked here but none of the proposed solutions have been working for me: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6392

**C#**

Model

```
public class Filter
{
    public string filterType { get; set; }

    public string filterKey { get; set; }

    public string filterValue { get; set; }
}
```

Controller Action

```
       public List<Filter> Filters { get; set; } = new List<Filter>()
        {
            new Filter()
            {
                filterType = "TypeA",
                filterValue = "ValueA",
                filterKey = "TypeA|ValueA"
            },
            new Filter()
            {
                filterType = "TypeB",
                filterValue = "ValueB",
                filterKey = "TypeB|ValueB"
            }
        };

    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Get()
    {
        var response = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Filters);

        return new JsonResult(response);
    }
```

I have confirmed with both POSTMAN and Chrome Developer Tool's that this controller is correctly returning the JSON:

```
    [{"filterType":"TypeA","filterValue":"TypeA","filterKey":"TypeA|ValueA"},
 {"filterType":"TypeB","filterValue":"ValueB","filterKey":"TypeB|ValueB"}]
```

**Angular**

Model (filter.ts)

```
export class Filter{
      filterType: string;
      filterKey: string;
      filterValue:string;
  }
```

Service (filter.service.ts)

```
   @Injectable()
export class FilterService {

  private apiUrl: string = "http://localhost:7639/api/filters";


  constructor(private http: Http) { }


  public getFilters = (): Observable<Filter[]> => {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        return this.http.get(this.apiUrl,options)
                         .map(res => <Filter[]>res.json())
                         .do(x => console.log(x)) <-- This clearly logs the JSON
                         .catch(this.handleError);

  }

  private handleError(error:Response){
    console.error(error);
    return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
  }

}
```

Component (filter.component.ts)

```
export class FilterComponent implements OnInit{
      title = 'Filters';
      public filters: Filter[];

      constructor(private filterService: FilterService) {

       }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.getFilters();
      }

      private getFilters(){
        this.filterService.getFilters().subscribe(filters => {
          this.filters = filters;
          console.log(filters);
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
        }, () => {

        });
      }
    }
```

Component HTML (filter.component.html)

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>

<div *ngFor="let filter of filters">
    <p>{{filter.filterType}}</p>
    <p>{{filter.filterValue}}</p>
    <p>{{filter.filterKey}}</p>
</div>
```

Any help with this would be appreciated

Comment: Try  `console.log(Array.isArray(filters));` I'm sure that your result is not array

Comment: @yurzui. You led me to the answer, thank you. When I logged typeof, I noticed it was a string; so I added JSON.Parse() around res.json(). It looks pretty gross but it's working now.

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes; that was it. Thank you; that was much, much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was super simple.

```
// GET api/values
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Get()
{
    var response = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Filters);

    return new JsonResult(response);
}
```

I was doing redundant serialization on the list and passing the response back as a string.

Changing the above method corrected the issue:

```
// GET api/values
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Get() => new JsonResult(Filters);
```